# Angular dynamically inject specific component

Tags: javascript, angular

I have 3 components, and I want to inject one of them into another components html based on the values received from a Get request:

Comp1, Comp2, Comp3

the current way is less than ideal, especially when 3 components may soon become 20

```
  <Comp1 *ngIf="data.value === 'comp_1'"></Comp1>
  <Comp2 *ngIf="data.value === 'comp_2'"></Comp2>
  <Comp3 *ngIf="data.value === 'comp_3'"></Comp3>
```

With React I can easily inject pieces of JSX via a function call, but I'm not sure on the best practices for doing this in Angular

Comment: Look at this -> https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-component-loader

Comment: You can use `ngSwitch` or something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36325212/angular-2-dynamic-tabs-with-user-click-chosen-components/36325468#36325468. See also https://angular.io/api/common/NgComponentOutlet

Comment: NgComponentOutlet is a much neater way of doing it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the `NgComponentOutlet` usage example. Let say you have two components:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component-one',
  template: `<p>I'm the Component 1</p>`
})
export class FirstDynamicComponent {}

@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-component-two',
  template: `<p>I'm the Component 2</p>`
})
export class SecondDynamicComponent {}
```

The component below loads the `FirstDynamicComponent` by default but replaces it with the `SecondDynamicComponent` if you click a button:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
    <button (click)="switchComponents()">Swith Components:</button>
    <ng-container *ngComponentOutlet="content"></ng-container>
  `
})
export class AppComponent  {
  comp1 = FirstDynamicComponent;
  comp2 = SecondDynamicComponent;

  content = this.comp1;

  switchComponents() {
    this.content = this.comp2;
  }
}
```

Don't forget to register both dynamic components in their module's `entryComponents` section:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [...],
  declarations: [ 
      AppComponent,
      FirstDynamicComponent,
      SecondDynamicComponent
  ],
  entryComponents: [
      FirstDynamicComponent,
      SecondDynamicComponent
  ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[**StackBlitz example**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-9vbask)